# SCCM 1802 - Scheduled deployment WOL not working, but RightClickTools WOL works

Tags: deployment, sccm, wake-on-lan

I have been trying to figure out why Wake On Lan works for Right Click Tools, but not for SCCM Scheduled Deployments.

In the **wolmgr.log** file I found this happening every five seconds: "*Failed to get WOL inbox on AMT Proxy component. Wait 5 seconds... SMS_WAKEONLAN_MANAGER 9/19/2018 11:32:24 AM 480 (0x01E0)*".

In the **wolcmgr.log** file I don't see any errors except this happening about four times a day, which I think is referring to the endless errors shown in the other log file: "*CBaseCounter::Initialize - Registered performance counter "Total Number of Packets failed" SMS_WAKEONLAN_COMMUNICATION_MANAGER 9/19/2018 2:01:59 AM 9496 (0x2518)*"

I have tried to look up these error messages and haven't found anything to help me get this resolved.

I have tried various ports, including the default (9) and 12287, currently it is on 7. We are being told to use subnet directed broadcasts by our network team due to some limitations with our Cisco network configuration.

I do have a SQL Server Agent (ADK) service that was disabled. I enabled it and it starts but turns off immediately. I don't know if that is related at all. I did have some deployment issues with Windows 7 drivers giving errors during the task sequence, even though they were installing. So I installed a Windows 8.1 ADK after seeing an article about bugs with the latest Win10 ADK and SCCM Task Sequences installing Win7 drivers. I've since then installed Win10 1703 ADK, which works on one of my other SCCM servers on Win7 deployments fine, and I was having this WOL problem before installing 1703 ADK.

Under Administration > System Status > Site Status > Management Point, when I show messages I see these:

*Description Severity
Type Site code
Date / Time System
Component Message ID
Thread ID Process ID
The Wake On LAN component has failed to read the site control file settings.    Possible cause: The information is not yet available.  Solution: The component is waiting for the information to become available and will retry obtaining the information at its next interval. Error
Milestone CML
9/20/2018 12:47:56 PM SMS_WAKEONLAN_MANAGER
6500 3384
3988

Description Severity
Type Site code
Date / Time System
Component Message ID
Thread ID Process ID
The Wake On LAN component has failed to read the site control file settings.    Possible cause: The information is not yet available.  Solution: The component is waiting for the information to become available and will retry obtaining the information at its next interval. Error
Milestone CML
9/20/2018 9:39:03 AM SMS_WAKEONLAN_MANAGER
6500 2924
2636*

[ADK SQL Server Agent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1MAGy.png)

[SCCM WOL configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVGb9.png)

[WOL ports](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zx6MA.png)

[wolmgr.log file screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76e7Z.png)

[RightClickTools WOL Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HofUb.png)

Comment: Afaik the right click tools send the WoL signal themselves from your client so this does neither use the same settings as sccm nor come from the same subnet. So basically it is not really comparable. Could be that the network is not configured to allow the wol signal from the server (unless you use right click tools directly on the server) or that one uses unicast and one subnet-directed broadcast and you have to switch that to the working method

Comment: I am logged in to the server when using the right click tools so they are coming from the server.  Subnet directed broadcasts are not allowed from my workstation subnet.

Comment: Right click tools is using subnet directed broadcast method and works.

Comment: I've added an image of the Right Click Tools WOL config

Comment: I can't close this question, but I would like to.  I'm going to post a different question instead.